# Implementing a interface with template function with a template class C#

Tags: c#, templates, generic-programming

I want to implement a interface with a template function. The implemented class is also a template class. I want to make sure that template parameter of the implemented function is same as the that of the class

```
public interface A
{
    T SetValue<T>(T v);
}

public class B<ValType> : A
{
    ValType val;

    public T SetValue<T>(T v)
    {
        val = v;
    }
}
```

the value of the "val" should need to set only if T == ValType, Is there any way to do it in compile time.

Comment: You could solve this by making A generic (`A<T>`) and then `public class B<ValType> : A<ValType>` in which case SetValue is no longer generic

Comment: I want to store the type A in a common container 
    

    A[] val= new A[2]; 

    va[0] = new B<int>(); 
    val[1] = new B<float>(); 

    val[0].SetValue<int>(0); 
    val[1].SetValue<float>(10.0); 
    val[0].SetValue<float>(2.0f); // Should give an error

Answer (score 1):

One option: promote the type to the interface:

```
interface A<T>
{
    T SetValue(T v);
}
```

Then implement the interface providing the type:

```
class B<ValType> : A<ValType>
{
    public ValType SetValue(ValType v) 
    { 
        return v;
    }
}
```

Do note, from this point forwards the interface will be used by it's closed generic type:

```
A<int> ia = GetB(); // whatever.
```

Comment: I want to store the type A in a common array

    A[] val= new A[2];
    va[0] = new B<int>();
    val[1] = new B<float>();

    val[0].SetValue<int>(0);
    val[1].SetValue<float>(10.0);

    val[0].SetValue<float>(2.0f); // Should give an error

Comment: @Parag In that case, no. Any checks you do will need to be at run-time. I cannot think of a way this would work at compile-time without some sort of concession.